# Regex to exclude first and last characters of match

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I've the following string:
word_word2_word3_word4

My intention is to extract only 'test2'. Using `_\w*?_` as string match, I can get '*word2*' as match, but I can't see a way of removing those underscores to match only 'word2'.

I can't use .split() or something like it, this value must be gathered using Regex only.

What modifications do you suggest guys?

Comment: Why not use String.split("_")[1] ?

Comment: Cant do String.split("_")[1]  because it will be interpreted by a client, and it must be configurable.

Comment: From the question I assume that you need second word. What changes would have you to make to the code with `split` that you won't need to code with Regex ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use positive lookahead and lookbehind

`(?<=_)\w*2(?=_)`

> My intention is to extract only 'test2'. Using *\w*?* as string match, I can get 'word2' as a match, but I can't see a way of removing those underscores to match only 'word2'.

The underscores won't be part of the matching string but will be before and after it

EDIT:

Going further, if the match string is on the beginning or end of the whole text, it won't be surrounded by underscores.

`(?<=_|^)[^_]*2(?=_|$)`

This one makes optional the use of underscore in this specific situation.

[online test](https://regex101.com/r/K3eJuF/1)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! :) :)

Comment: Why do you have `2` in your regex. What if input is `abc_foo_pqr_bar`?

Comment: The user asked for matching a text with the `2` enclosed (`test2`). If the case were `abc_foo_pqr_bar` then would be no matches...

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but assuming that `word2`, `word3`, etc are arbitrary words which don't contain `_`, you can use capturing groups to extract a subset of the characters that want to extract. For example:

```
\w*_(\w*)_\w*_\w*
```

That matches your string and the first (and only) capture group extracts the second word. Maybe the `*` should be `+` depending on whether you want to accept zero-sized words.

Comment: Hello @BeeOnRope, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately if I use your regex it matches all the string. I just want the "word2" without any underscores. Do you have any modification on it?

Comment: What do you mean by _want_? The code above matches the entire string, but _gives you_ only `word2` when you query for the first matched group (the part `(\w*)`).  If you care about _matching_ you could use a combination of lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: I've used http://regexr.com/ , applied this regex with word1_word2_word3_word4 string and it matches all of this, not only word2 .

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to do that if your not worried about performance would to just remove the first and last character of a match.

Comment: It cant be done because it the clients must be able to configure it in anyway that they want. This is one string that I need to match only.